# Cakephp, ordering associated tables

Tags: php, cakephp, model, associations

When I search a model which "has many" of something else.

For example a blog post has many categories.

When searching for blog post with categories associated, how do I order the associated categories? When the array is returned it ignores the order on the category model and defaults to it's usual id order.

Cheers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In addition you can set the order in your model's relation.

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        ...
        'order' => 'Category.name DESC',
        ....
    ),
}?>
```

Answer (score 4):

in cakephp 3 use 'sort' instead of 'order':

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        ...
        'sort' => 'Category.name DESC',
        ....
    ),
}?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the ContainableBehavior:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('contain' => array(
    'Category' => array(
        'order' => 'Category.created DESC'
    )
)));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1325/Containing-deeper-associations

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `order` attribute of the `find` method parameters. Otherwise, it will default to the order for the top-most/parent Model. In your case the `Category.id`.

Comment: The associated model is ordered on the model itself, where do you add it it the find when your getting associated 'has many' on a model?

Comment: Post the code that you are using to retrieve your model data or take a look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find. I believe you want set the `order` parameter.

Comment: A hasMany relationship implies 2 separate queries - when you set the order attribute on the find method, you get an error because the associated model is not included in the original query and thus 'does not exist'.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by columns in associated models requires setting `sortWhitelist`.

```
$this->paginate['order'] = [ 'Fees.date_incurred' => 'desc' ];
$this->paginate['sortWhitelist'] = ['Fees.date_incurred', 'Fees.amount'];
$this->paginate['limit'] = $this->paginate['maxLimit'] = 200;
```